# TDLib UnsatisfiedLinkError (no tdjni in java.library.path)

Tags: java, maven, unsatisfiedlinkerror, tdlib

I'm currently struggling to install TDLib for my JAVA project but it always shows the error:
`java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: no tdjni in java.library.path`

At first, i tried to create a **Maven** project, then import the required dependency. Here's my pom.xml:

```
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>telegram</groupId>
  <artifactId>project</artifactId>
  <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <properties>
    <maven.compiler.source>1.8</maven.compiler.source>
    <maven.compiler.target>1.8</maven.compiler.target>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <junit.version>5.6.0</junit.version>
    <maven-enforcer-plugin.version>3.0.0-M3</maven-enforcer-plugin.version>
    <maven-checkstyle-plugin.version>3.1.2</maven-checkstyle-plugin.version>
    <checkstyle.version>8.45.1</checkstyle.version>
    <maven-surefire-plugin.version>3.0.0-M5</maven-surefire-plugin.version>
    <jacoco-maven-plugin.version>0.8.4</jacoco-maven-plugin.version>
    <maven-javadoc-plugin.version>3.0.0</maven-javadoc-plugin.version>
    <!-- JaCoCo thresholds. Increase gradually as you add tests. -->
    <jacoco.unit-tests.limit.instruction-ratio>0%</jacoco.unit-tests.limit.instruction-ratio>
    <jacoco.unit-tests.limit.branch-ratio>0%</jacoco.unit-tests.limit.branch-ratio>
    <jacoco.unit-tests.limit.class-complexity>20</jacoco.unit-tests.limit.class-complexity>
    <jacoco.unit-tests.limit.method-complexity>5</jacoco.unit-tests.limit.method-complexity>
  </properties>
  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
      <artifactId>junit-jupiter-api</artifactId>
      <version>${junit.version}</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
      <artifactId>junit-jupiter-engine</artifactId>
      <version>${junit.version}</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
    <groupId>ca.denisab85</groupId>
    <artifactId>tdlib</artifactId>
    <version>v1.8.8-20221107</version>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>
  <build>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-enforcer-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>${maven-enforcer-plugin.version}</version>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <goals>
              <goal>enforce</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
              <rules>
                <requireMavenVersion>
                  <version>3.6.3</version>
                </requireMavenVersion>
              </rules>
              <fail>true</fail>
            </configuration>
          </execution>
        </executions>
      </plugin>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-checkstyle-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>${maven-checkstyle-plugin.version}</version>
        <dependencies>
          <dependency>
            <groupId>com.puppycrawl.tools</groupId>
            <artifactId>checkstyle</artifactId>
            <version>${checkstyle.version}</version>
          </dependency>
          <dependency>
            <groupId>com.github.ngeor</groupId>
            <artifactId>checkstyle-rules</artifactId>
            <version>4.9.3</version>
          </dependency>
        </dependencies>
        <configuration>
          <configLocation>com/github/ngeor/checkstyle.xml</configLocation>
          <includeTestSourceDirectory>true</includeTestSourceDirectory>
          <skip>${skipTests}</skip>
        </configuration>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <id>checkstyle</id>
            <phase>validate</phase>
            <goals>
              <goal>check</goal>
            </goals>
          </execution>
        </executions>
      </plugin>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>${maven-surefire-plugin.version}</version>
      </plugin>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.jacoco</groupId>
        <artifactId>jacoco-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>${jacoco-maven-plugin.version}</version>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <id>pre-unit-test</id>
            <goals>
              <goal>prepare-agent</goal>
            </goals>
          </execution>
          <execution>
            <id>post-unit-test</id>
            <phase>test</phase>
            <goals>
              <goal>report</goal>
            </goals>
          </execution>
          <execution>
            <id>check-unit-test</id>
            <phase>test</phase>
            <goals>
              <goal>check</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
              <dataFile>${project.build.directory}/jacoco.exec</dataFile>
              <rules>
                <rule>
                  <element>BUNDLE</element>
                  <limits>
                    <limit>
                      <counter>INSTRUCTION</counter>
                      <value>COVEREDRATIO</value>
                      <minimum>${jacoco.unit-tests.limit.instruction-ratio}</minimum>
                    </limit>
                    <limit>
                      <counter>BRANCH</counter>
                      <value>COVEREDRATIO</value>
                      <minimum>${jacoco.unit-tests.limit.branch-ratio}</minimum>
                    </limit>
                  </limits>
                </rule>
                <rule>
                  <element>CLASS</element>
                  <limits>
                    <limit>
                      <counter>COMPLEXITY</counter>
                      <value>TOTALCOUNT</value>
                      <maximum>${jacoco.unit-tests.limit.class-complexity}</maximum>
                    </limit>
                  </limits>
                </rule>
                <rule>
                  <element>METHOD</element>
                  <limits>
                    <limit>
                      <counter>COMPLEXITY</counter>
                      <value>TOTALCOUNT</value>
                      <maximum>${jacoco.unit-tests.limit.method-complexity}</maximum>
                    </limit>
                  </limits>
                </rule>
              </rules>
            </configuration>
          </execution>
        </executions>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>
  <reporting>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-javadoc-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>${maven-javadoc-plugin.version}</version>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </reporting>
</project>
```

Well, not succeeding in doing so, I then switched to do just like the guide on their github:
[Github link](https://github.com/tdlib/td)
[Build link](https://tdlib.github.io/td/build.html)

The same error occurs when I run their code.

After that, I looked up on the forum, they said that to fix this error, we need to specify the path to `java.library.path`. So I used the code `java - Djava.library.path=C:/Users/PC/td/tdlib/bin/tdjni.dll`

I did all of that, but none works.
I'm currently using **Windows OS**
I have one more **Mac M1**, but the same error happens here

Comment: `java -Djava.library.path=C:/Users/PC/td/tdlib/bin` is what you need

Comment: It's not working, it shows up java help

Comment: Is the dll in that directory?

Comment: no sir, the dll is not in the directory

Comment: Well that can't possibly work then;)